# Estimating mutual information with gaussian kde between two continuous variables in python

Tags: python, estimation, continuous-data, mutual-information

I am trying to write a python code to estimate the mutual information between two continuous variables in python, using a gaussian kde to estimate the probability distributions. Checking it with sklearns implementation, I get different results, but maybe its due to the different ways we are estimating it (kde vs nearest neighbors approach).

My method is based on the following:

$$ I(x_1, x_2)= H(x_1) + H(x_2) - H(x_1,x_2)$$
with $H(x_n)$ being the entropy of $H(x_n)$ and $H(x_1, x_2)$ being the joint entropy defined as:

$$H(x_n) = -\int p(x_n)log_2(p(x_n)) dx = -\mathbb{E}[log_2(p(x_n))]$$
$$H(x_1, x_2) = -\int \int p(x_1, x_2)log_2(p(x_1, x_2)) dx_1dx_2 = -\mathbb{E}[log_2(p(x_1, x_2))]$$

So I do two things:

- estimate the probability densities using [gaussian_kde](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) from scipy
- to calculate $H(x_N)$ I take the mean of $log_2(p(x_n))$ of my data points, same for the joint entropy, and multiply it by $-1$
- get the information as $H(x_1) + H(x_2) - H(x_1,x_2)$

Comparing it with sklearn, which uses a [nearest neighbor approach](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression.html#sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_regression) I get rather different results. As I do not have a big math/statistics background.

My problem is I cannot tell whether it is because:

- My logic is flawed
- My implementation is flawed
- Different ways of estimating the mutual info will give different results and that's it.

Code:

```py
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_regression
import numpy as np

#generate some data
x1 = np.linspace(-5, 5, num = 1000)
x2 = np.sin(x1) + 0.2*np.random.normal(size = 1000)
dataset = np.stack((x1,x2))

#kde of x1,x2 and joint x1,x2
kd_x1 = gaussian_kde(dataset[0,:])
kd_x2 = gaussian_kde(dataset[1,:])
kd_x1_x2 = gaussian_kde(dataset)

#entropy calculations
h_x1_x2 = -np.mean(np.log2(kd_x1_x2(dataset)))
h_x1 = -np.mean(np.log2(kd_x1(dataset[0,:])))
h_x2 = -np.mean(np.log2(kd_x2(dataset[1,:])))

#Information calculations
I_x1_x2_kde = (h_x1 + h_x2 - h_x1_x2)
I_x1_x2_sklearn = mutual_info_regression(x2.reshape(-1,1),x1)

print(f"Mutual information using kde: {I_x1_x2_kde}")
print(f"Mutual information using sklear (nearest neighbors): {I_x1_x2_sklearn}")
```

Comment: Could you explain what "take the mean of the log of the probabilities of the data points" amounts to?  This doesn't seem to bear much of a relationship with mutual information.

Comment: I calculate the entropy of x as the negative expected value of log(p(x)), so the mean of log(p(x)) for the data points. Will edit to see id makes more sense.

Comment: Your estimate is exquisitely sensitive to the method you use to estimate $p(x).$  That alone can explain any discrepancies you might be seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So it seems its a crummy/sensitive estimator then. Playing around with the bandwith does produce very different estimates. Thankfully this was a personal exercise.